# Sorting 2 columns in opposite direction does not work using expr function

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
rows = [("Ali", 0, [100]),("Barbara", 1, [300, 250, 100]),("Cesar", 1, [350, 100]),("Dongmei", 1, [400, 100]), ("Eli", 2, [250]),("Florita", 2, [500, 300, 100]),("Gatimu", 3, [300, 100])] 

df=spark.createDataFrame(rows,["name", "department", "score"])
```

I run the command shown below but the data does not sort on "name" column in descending order. I do not get any error as well.

```
df.orderBy(expr('department'),expr('name desc')).show()
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

If we take a look at the documentation of `expr(...)`, it is used to create a column out of sql like semantics. `expr` only supports expressions that is supported by `selectClause only` and so you can't put `order by` expressions inside `expr`.

```scala
/**
   * Parses the expression string into the column that it represents, similar to
   * [[Dataset#selectExpr]].
   * {{{
   *   // get the number of words of each length
   *   df.groupBy(expr("length(word)")).count()
   * }}}
   *
   * @group normal_funcs
   */
  def expr(expr: String): Column = { ...
}
```

Regarding the expression you used in the orderBy `expr('name desc')`, it will be translated as

```
name AS `desc`
```

which is incorrect.

there are 2 variants of `Dataframe#orderBy` as of `2.4.5`-

1. one takes string columns without any sort order as below-

```
def orderBy(sortCol: String, sortCols: String*): Dataset[T] = sort(sortCol, sortCols : _*)
```

2. Another accepts column where you can specify sort order as below-

```scala
/**
   * Returns a new Dataset sorted by the given expressions. For example:
   * {{{
   *   ds.sort($"col1", $"col2".desc)
   * }}}
   *
   * @group typedrel
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def sort(sortExprs: Column*): Dataset[T] = {
```

try using below 2 optios-

```scala
// otption-1
df.orderBy($"department", $"name".desc).show(false) // works
// option-2
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
    spark.sql("select * from df order by department, name desc") // works
      .show(false)
```

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, asc
df.orderBy(expr("count desc")).show(2)   -- these lines are from Spark definitive guide book on page 85.

Comment: Please raise a bug on the github then quoting this stackoverflow query

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is a bug, personnalyl I would rather use the `col` and `desc` functions and it will work with the intended behavior:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

rows = [
    ("Ali", 0, [100]),
    ("Barbara", 1, [300, 250, 100]),
    ("Cesar", 1, [350, 100]),
    ("Dongmei", 1, [400, 100]),
    ("Eli", 2, [250]),
    ("Florita", 2, [500, 300, 100]),
    ("Gatimu", 3, [300, 100])
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows,["name", "department", "score"])

df.orderBy(col("department"), col("name").desc()).show()
```

Comment: You are right, but the there is an example in Spark Definitve Guide which gives an example of orderBy using expr. I just extended that example to multiple columns with opposite sort direction and it does not work.Why?